# pass names from one page to another using jquery or javascript in winRT

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, windows-runtime, winjs

I want to pass four names taken as input from user in first page to another page by navigating in **winRT app** using **winJS or jquery**.

Suppose the four names are

```
1.akshay
2.ashish
3.pavitra
4.adarsh
```

how this is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

this should do.

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/otherpage/page.html', 
   { param1: value1, param2:value2, });
```

Also, need to check if the user entered data is it session state? that is if the app where to suspend and terminate and reactivate - should the form be prefilled with the data user entered? if yes, refer `default.js: app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {}`

Comment: i want to implement this coding in button

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `WinJS.Navigation.navigate` function state property for transferring data from one page to other pages. Let's say we need to send these four names to the different page.

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/Details.html", { Name1: name1, Name2: name2,Name3: name3,Name4: name4, });
```

then in the `details.js` we can retrieve these values:

```
var myState = WinJS.Navigation.state;

if(document.getElementById("name1"))
    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = myState.Name1;

if(document.getElementById("name2"))
    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = myState.Name2;

if(document.getElementById("name3"))
    document.getElementById("name3").innerHTML = myState.Name3;

if(document.getElementById("name4"))
    document.getElementById("name4").innerHTML = myState.Name4;
```

Answer (score 0):

done using this technique 
        in default.html

```
$(function () {
               $('#navigate12').click(function () {
                var te = $("#text1").val();
                var text2 = $("#text2").val();
                var text3 = $("#text3").val();
                var text4 = $("#text4").val();
                window.location.href = "/page.html?cal=" + te + "&text2=" + text2 +
               "&text3=" + text3 + "&text4=" + text4; <-- this line has changes to include multiple parameters rest is same as in the question
```

and in page.html

```
    <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {                  
              function qs() {
                var qsparam = new Array(10);
                var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var parms = query.split('&');
               for (var i = 0; i < parms.length; i++) {
               var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
               if (pos > 0)
              {
                        var key = parms[i].substring(0, pos);
                        var val = parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
                        qsparam[i] = val;    
              }                          
                                                       }
               text1.value = qsparam[0];
               text2.value = qsparam[1];
               text3.value = qsparam[2];
               text4.value = qsparam[3];



              }
              var splitstr = qs();



                    });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <input id="text1" type="text" />
    <input id="text2" type="text" />
   <input id="text3" type="text" />
    <input id="text4" type="text" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

we are calling the function qs() using

var splitstr = qs();

it splits the parameters and to see the value of different variable u can use text1.value=parms 
if any doubt u can ask :-)